# android drawable from file path

Tags: android, drawable, filepath

I have a file path String of the form "e:\...\xxx.jpg"
How do I create a drawable from it?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You can create a Drawable or Bitmap from a string path like this:

```
String pathName = "/path/to/file/xxx.jpg"; 
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
```

For a Bitmap:

```
String pathName = "/path/to/file/xxx.jpg";
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
```

Comment: I used to load bitmaps to ImageViews. But thanks to your answer, I just tried to convert my jpg assets into Drawables and now my app loads faster.

Comment: Simple, neat and clean! +1 for keeping it TL;DR :)